# Cannot pipe output from python command

Tags: django, linux

I am trying to backup a django app via the built in "dumpdata" command:

python manage.py dumpdata --exclude=contenttypes --indent=4 > path_to_dumped_data.json

But the json data is being printed to the screen and the file remains empty

Any ideas

(python2.6, django 1.2.3, Ubuntu 10.04 LTS)

Comment: dumpdata definitely prints to stdout by default. What happens when you run $ python manage.py dumpdata --exclude=contenttypes --indent=4 > /dev/null ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `&>` or `2>`. Although weird, the output might be printed to standard error output.

Comment: Just to check I ran this via the subprocess module - nothing went to stdout, everything to stderr with an error code of 0!

Comment: That seems like bad behavior to me. According to http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#dumpdata-appname-appname-appname-model dumpdata "Outputs to standard output" so that's clearly a bug. I've submitted a bug here: http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/14847